# Setar valores dentro ou fora do método?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, método

Estou estudando sobre a passagem de parâmetros no PHP. Eu quero, por exemplo, usar um determinado método que precisa receber dois valores, tenho os seguintes códigos:

#### Exemplo 1

Na `class`:

```
class Exemplo {
        protected $var1, $var2;
        
        public function setVar1($value){
           $this->var1 = $value;
           return $this;
        }
        public function setVar2($value){
           $this->var2 = $value;
           return $this;
        }
    
        public function exemplo(){
           $dado1 = $this->var1;
           $dado2 = $this->var2;
        }
}
```

E a chamada

```
 $exe = new Exemplo();
 $exe->setVar1('dado1')
     ->setVar2('dado2')
     ->exemplo();
```

Ou

#### Exemplo 2

Na `class`:

```
class Exemplo {
   public function exemplo($var1, $var2)
   {
      $dado1 = $var1;
      $dado2 = $var2;
   }
}
```

E a chamada

```
 $exe = new Exemplo();
 $exe->exemplo('dado1', 'dado2');
```

Aparentemente os dois códigos fazem o mesmo, e o Exemplo 2 claramente é bem mais simples de se fazer, gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre eles além da escrita, e/ou qual seria a forma mais correta (se existir) ou melhor. E em termos de segurança e velocidade eles possuem diferença?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bom, nessa pergunta os dois exemplos não são equivalentes. Em ambos o método `exemplo()` não faz nada útil de fato. Atribuir valores para variáveis locais e não fazer nada com eles não faz sentido. Então faça o mais simples, o que tem menos passos. Eu diria que é o exemplo 2, mas até ele é desnecessário.

Se o método fosse:

```
public function exemplo($var1, $var2) {
    $dado1 = $this->var1 = $var1;
    $dado2 = $this->var1 = $var2;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/SetThis.php).

Aí a diferença é que o segundo você garante que as duas propriedades são atribuídas juntas. É uma operação atômica. No primeiro exemplo é possível fazer de forma separada.

Não há diferença relevante de velocidade. Segurança propriamente não muda nada. É uma questão de intenção. Se as duas propriedades precisam ser mudadas juntas, o primeiro exemplo é errado. Se eles precisam, mesmo que eventualmente serem mudadas independentemente, o segundo é errado.

Então não tem melhor, tem o certo e o errado. E depende da situação.

Nesse exemplo eu diria que tanto faz. Em um exemplo mais concreto, depende. Tem muita regrinha que as pessoas escrevem e vários programadores seguem que não fazem sentido. Se você seguir cegamente, acaba fazendo errado.

De uma maneira geral sé deve criar métodos *setters* se tiver um bom motivo para isso. Se não encontrar uma boa justificativa para criá-los, não crie.

Answer (score 3):

Isso é uma questão de escopo e ecapsulamento.
A pergunta é você vai usar esses valores fora do escopo do método?
Se sim, talvez seja interessante usar os "set".

Você vai precisar tratar/validar esses dados na entrada?
Se sim definitivamente é melhor usar o "set"
Partindo dos conceitos de SOLID responsabilidade única,é melhor realizar o tratamento da informação em um método certo pra isso no caso seria o Set.

Edit: Ah esqueci, tem a questão do controle de acesso na informação. Caso essa informação vá ser usada somente dentro da classe e não é para ficar aberta talvez seja interessante definir as variaveis como private e usar o set mesmo.